# Call by reference-or- Call by value

Tags: java, arrays, oop, call-by-value

```
class Box {
    int size;

    Box(int s) {
        size = s;
    }
}

public class Laser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box b1 = new Box(5);
        Box[] ba = go(b1, new Box(6));
        ba[0] = b1;
        for (Box b : ba)
            System.out.print(b.size + " ");
    }

    static Box[] go(Box b1, Box b2) {
        b1.size = 4;
        Box[] ma = { b2, b1 };
        return ma;
    }
}

What the result? 
A. 4 4 
B. 5 4 
C. 6 4 
D. 4 5 
E. 5 5 
F. Compilation fails
```

The answer is A

I am having hard time trying to understand the results of this code. Can anyone explain the results to me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some explanations -

**1.** First of all you have create a `Box` in main() class -

```
 Box b1 = new Box(5);
```

**2.** Then send b1 to go() method -

```
   Box[] ba = go(b1, new Bo(6));
```

Now `b1.size` is 5

**3.** In method go() you are setting `b1.size` to 4 using the assignment statement -

```
b1.size = 4;
```

**4.** Now you are creating a new `Box` array `ma`  -

```
Box[] ma = { b2, b1 };
```

In this array the first element is b2 and `b2.size` is 6. See point 2.

**5.** Then you return `ma` and at point 2 the returned array `ma` is assigned with `ba`. Now the first element of the array is 6 and the second element of the array is 4.

**6.** `ba[0] = b1;` - this statement sets the first element of `ba[0]` to `b1`. Note at point 2 `b1.size` was set to 4.

Now `ba[0].size` is 4
and `ba[1].size` is 4

And that's why the output is `4 4`

Comment: In  Point 1 in Box b1 = new Box(5);  are we creating a variable or an array of length 5 ?

Comment: We are creating a new variable `b1` of type `Box`. In java we create array like as follows:  `int[] intArray = new int(5)`.

Comment: So does Box b1 = new Box(5);   means that we are creating variable of length 5 or value 5 ? Is that the same thing like saying b1 = 5 ?

Comment: No it's not the same of b1 = 5. Here `b1` is of type `Box` and 5 is int. So we can not assign `b1` to 5. It would be a wrong assignment. The `new Box(5)` create a new object of type `Box` using the constructor `Box(int size)`.  After that the newly created object of `Box` with size 5 is assigned with `b1`.

Answer (score 3):

In Java it is always **pass by value**

Primitives are always **pass by value**

Objects are passed by their references and those references are also **passed by value**.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box b1 = new Box(5); //Line1
        Box[] ba = go(b1, new Box(6)); //Line2
        ba[0] = b1; //Line3
        for (Box b : ba)
            System.out.print(b.size + " ");
    }
```

The answer is (4 4) because,

- In line1 you're initializing the `size` of `Box` to 5 inside the
  constructor.
- In line 2 you're sending two objects as arguments to the method
  `go()`. The `size` of object referred by b1 is now 5 and the `new Box(6);`
  object has size 6. Inside the method, you're changing the value of
  1st parameter from 5 to 4. And finally you returned array `ma` with `b2`
  as first element and `b1` as second element. `b2` has value 6 and `b1` has 4.
- Now in the line 3 you're again changing the value of first element
  inside the array. You replaced the first element inside the array `b2` which has a value 6 with `b1` whose
  value now is 4.

Answer (score 2):

When `Box[ ] ba = go (b1, new Bo(6));` is run, `go` instantiates `ba` with the following array: `[b2,b1]`, where `b2` has a size of 6 and `b1` has a size of 4. To be clear, `go` sets the size of b1 from 5 to 4. When b1, is passed to `go`, it is passed by *reference*, which means any changes to `b1` inside `go` are also changes made to the `b1` object that was created in the first line of `main`.

Then the following code is run:

```
ba[0] = b1;
```

Here, you're setting `b2` from within the array(since `ba[0]` refers to `b2`) equal to `b1`. Now, both `b2` and `b1` refer to a box with a size of 4.

P.S. Fun fact, objects never directly *equal* data; objects are only addresses which *correspond to* or *refer* to data written elsewhere on the stack. So, technically, when `ba[0] = b1;` is run, `b2` is simply *referring* to the same data that `b1` is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

In java all the primitive types are passed by value while the rest, like Objects or arrays are passed by reference.
It means that when you call the method

```
go(Box b1, Box b2)
```

it changes the value of b1.size everywhere because it sets b1.size = 4, so the result is A: 4 4

Comment: "Objects or Arrays are passed by reference and those references are passed by value". This would be more correct IMO.

Comment: Yep you're right. What i wanted to say is that all changes to an object are reflected in the whole program